# Decidability of $\{p|∃y : \operatorname{Dom}(φ p ) ⊇ \operatorname{Dom}(φ y )\}$

Tags: computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

I need to classify the set
$$\{p|∃y : \operatorname{Dom}(φ p ) ⊇ \operatorname{Dom}(φ y )\}$$
as decidable, semidecidable or not semidecidable.

I don't know how to start. Any ideas?

Dom (φp) it's all the inputs that are accepted by a turing machine "p", and the same for Dom (φy). 
So if My(some input) accepts then Mp(same input) accepts too, Mp can accept more inputs than My but not less.

But I don't know how work with that.

Comment: What are your ideas on the topic?

Comment: I have added my ideas on the question.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your notation, but it seems that your set contains everything, since you cal always choose $y = p$.